# Latex environment for English like algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I want to write the algorithm in latex. I don't want to use for example a code given below:

```
\begin{algorithm}

  \caption{Counting mismatches between two packed \DNA{} strings
    \label{alg:packed-dna-hamming}}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require{$x$ and $y$ are packed \DNA{} strings of equal length $n$}
    \Statex
    \Function{Distance}{$x, y$}
      \Let{$z$}{$x \oplus y$} \Comment{$\oplus$: bitwise exclusive-or}
      \Let{$\delta$}{$0$}
      \For{$i \gets 1 \textrm{ to } n$}
        \If{$z_i \neq 0$}
          \Let{$\delta$}{$\delta + 1$}
        \EndIf
      \EndFor
      \State \Return{$\delta$}
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

The problem with above code is that it is  pseudocode. But my algorithm consists of English sentences only. Is there an better way to write such kind of algorithms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just have a list of items showing a sequence of events/steps, it would suffice to use a regular list (like `enumerate` or `itemize`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

Consider the following structured approach:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item This is the first sentence that contains a description of
    what is important to do.
  \item There is more in this sentence.
  \item \lipsum[1]
  \item A final sentence describing a warp-up of what should be
    performed to complete the process you're want to discuss.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) can also be used in the way you suggest - sentences:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{This is an algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State This is the first sentence that contains a description of
      what is important to do.
    \State There is more in this sentence.
    \State \lipsum[1]
    \State A final sentence describing a warp-up of what should be
      performed to complete the process you're want to discuss.
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) is also an option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\LinesNumbered

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{This is an algorithm}
  This is the first sentence that contains a description of
    what is important to do.\;
  There is more in this sentence.\;
  \lipsum*[1]\;
  A final sentence describing a warp-up of what should be
    performed to complete the process you're want to discuss.\;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```